# In spring accessing service class in controller and storing response in embedded class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have dao class is below

```
@Override
public List<PersonDTO> getAllEmployees(long companyId) {

    Query query = getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(User.class.getName() + ".getAllEmployee");
    query.setParameter("companyId", companyId);

    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(PersonDTO.class));
    return query.list();
}
```

I have services class is below

```
public List<PersonDTO> getAllEmployees(long companyId) {

    try {
        return userDAO.getAllEmployees(companyId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(e);
    }
}
```

I have Embedded class

```
public class EntityListResponce implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<PersonDTO> personDTO;

    public List<PersonDTO> getPersonDTO() {
        return PersonDTO;
    }

    public void setPersonDTO(List<PersonDTO> employeesList) {
        this.PersonDTO = employeesList;
    }

}
```

I written a controller like below.

```
@RequestMapping("/getAllEntitys.htm")
public void getAllEntities(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        ZSession zSession = getZSession(request);
        Long companyId = zSession.getCompanyId();

        EntityListResponce entityListResponce = new EntityListResponce();


        List<PersonDTO> employeesList =  personService.getAllEmployees(companyId);



        WebUtils.writeJSONResponse(response,
                getSerializer(request, EXCLUDE_FILES).deepSerialize(entityListResponce));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        writeException(request, response, e);
    }
}
```

}

Is it proper way to collect all the employeesList like this

```
List<PersonDTO> employeesList = personService.getAllEmployees(companyId);
```

I am getting not getting all the employeesList in response.

Comment: Well, you never call entityListResponce.setPersonDTO() anywhere. Why don't you **return** it, BTW, and let Spring do the JSON serialization for you? And why don't you remove the setter and take the list as an argument of the constructor? This mistake would become impossible.

Comment: first check in the DAO method if the respective data has been fetched or not using debugging